# Getting segmentation fault when reassigning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Here's the fragment of a large code that is causing the error:

```
Class TreeNode {
private:
    int level;
    TreeNode* parentNode;
public:
    TreeNode() {
        level = 0;
        parentNode = NULL;
    }

    void setParent (TreeNode* n) {
        parentNode = n; // <- this reassignment is causing segmentation fault
    }
}
```

How can I reassign properly the pointer variable `parentNode`?

As @galinette tried to point it out, I might have called `setParent` from a null pointer. But, I check it beforehand in this way:

```
if (candidateChild != NULL) {
    candidateChild -> setParent(this); // <- I checked that both this and candidatChild are not NULL
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you called setParent from a null or invalid pointer to a TreeNode. The code shown here is not enough, you should post a complete example

Comment: @Bek Abdik I am sure that the error  occurs in the code snippet where this member function is called.

Comment: Start using `nullptr` from today please.

Comment: Could you please also post the piece of code where you instantiate `TreeNode` and how you call `setParent()` upon? The line you marked definitely should not call a segmentation fault, it's most likely the things around the call.

Comment: Also, post syntactically valid code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a null pointer that causes this, it might as well be an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Is this a base class for anything? Maybe the memory layout is corrupt when using polymorphism inproperly. Are there any other classes involved?

Comment: candidateChild may be non null, but invalid (non initialized, or pointing to a deleted instance). Use your debugger to figure out

Comment: Do you get the same error when you are hard-code `parentNode = nullptr` in the line you marked?

Comment: @PuerNoctis, yes same error

Comment: @BekAbdik Ok, although the comment section might now burst, could you give details on: Is it Linux/Windows you are running the program on? Which compiler do you use? Are you mixing runtimes (e.g. different libstdc++ or MSVC, or libs which use different ones)? Are you using inheritance somewhere? Do you have optimization enabled during compilation? Since this seems very strange, any info might help.

Answer (score 3):

The `setParent` fonction has no problem by itself. But you likely called it from an invalid pointer to a `TreeNode` (such as a null/uninitialized/deleted pointer)

Your code is valid, the error comes from another part that you did not post.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `TreeNode** parentNode` as a private field, and use `*parentNode=&n` for assignment.

Comment: public/private doesn't concern the runtime, this is all smoke and mirrors after compilation!

Comment: I dont get your point. It has nothing to do with public/private. This issue is obviously caused by incorrect use of pointers.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a private field, it could very well be a public field, doesn't matter. In that sense yes, it indeed does not have anything to do with it, but your answer implies that, hence my comment. Also `TreeNode**` with an assignment of `*parentNode=&n` would cause a fault if the pointer wasn't initialize first. The issue is not how he constructed his class, it's probably a wrong call as many have described in the other comments

Comment: @Bek Abdik He has to post all necessary info to identify this issue. Still, is this a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: @frogcdcn title of the question says segmentation fault. It's a runtime error.

Comment: Maybe his compiler is segfaulting :)